# dataGridView - можно ли убрать TopLeftHeaderCell (-1 колонку)?

Tags: c#

Или правильно этот элемент назвать "-1" колонкой? В данном dataGridView всегда максимум одна строка, и по этому данная колонка не нужна. Можно ли что-то сделать?
[image: TopLeftHeaderCell]

Answer (score 2):

Используй DataGridView.RowHeadersVisible Property